# error when I execute the command source ~/.bashrc

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

```
/home/my-pc/.bashrc:16: command not found: shopt
/home/my-pc/.bashrc:24: command not found: shopt
/home/my-pc/.bashrc:111: command not found: shopt
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:51: command not found: shopt
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:57: command not found: complete
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:62: command not found: complete
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:65: command not found: complete
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:68: command not found: complete
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:71: command not found: complete
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:74: command not found: complete
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:77: command not found: complete
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:80: command not found: complete
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:83: command not found: complete
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:86: command not found: complete
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:89: command not found: complete
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:92: command not found: complete
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion:314: parse error near `\n'
\[\e]0;\u@\h: \w\a\]\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]$
```

this is the output

Comment: What shell are you using? `shopt` and `complete` are both bash commands, and will not be available in other shells.

Comment: shell Oh My ZSH

Comment: `shopt` and `complete` are not zsh commands. `.bashrc` is intended to be sourced in bash.

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to the default shell of the linux which is set to zsh and to change that we can use the following command:

```
chsh -s /bin/bash
```

and then source your bash file to export the paths present in it:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

If your shell is zsh, make your edits in `~/.zshrc` instead of .bashrc.

When you're done, save the file using `:wq` (assuming you're using vim) and run this command:

```
source ~/.zshrc
```

Remember to remove whatever changes you've made to .bashrc, so it doesn't get executed twice.